# Query dataframe but apply filter only to rows where column value is not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, filter, nan

I have a dataframe df:

```
num1 | count | count_min | count_max
a    | 10    | 5         | 10
b    | 15    | 6         | 11
c    | 3     | NaN       | NaN
```

I want to filter out every count which is not between count_min and count_max.

But if count_min/count_max is NaN the row should be kept.

End result should be:

```
num1 | count | count_min | count_max
a    | 10    | 5         | 10
c    | 3     | NaN       | NaN
```

So I need something like an if/else in my query to check if count_min/count_max is NaN before I apply the filter.

How can I achieve this with query syntax like:

```
df = df.query("count >= count_min and count <= count_max")
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
In [4487]: df = df[df['count'].between(df.count_min, df.count_max) | (df.count_max.isna() | df.count_min.isna())]

In [4487]: df
Out[4487]: 
  num1  count  count_min  count_max
0    a     10        5.0       10.0
2    c      3        NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where()` for this case and the use it as filter:

```
df[np.where((df['count'].between(df['count_min'].values,df['count_max'].values)) | (df['count_min'].isna()) | (df['count_max'].isna()),True,False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
df = df[(df['count_min'].isna()) | (df['count_min'].isna()) | ((df['count'] >= df['count_min'] & (df['count'] <= df['count_max']))]
```